# Detecting dotnet runtime version in wix installer

Tags: wix, .net-core

I am creating wix package for my software and have prerequisite to have .net core runtime 3.1.*. I am using below code to check whether .net core runtime exist or not.

It seems its not working or detecting. Please suggest how to detect .netcore runtime in wix.

```
 <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedfx\Microsoft.NETCore.App"
                     Result="exists"
                     Variable="NetCore3_x64_Installed"
                     Win64="yes"
                     />
<bal:Condition Message="This application requires .NET Runtime 3.1.4. Please install the .NET Runtime 3.1.4 then run this installer again.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NetCore3_x64_Installed]]>
</bal:Condition>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that there are a list of keys inside Microsoft.NETCore.App.